# Advanced annotating of faceted box plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good day to all R specialists!

I have a faceted box plot, created with the `ggplot2` library:

```
true_1 <- c(1,2,3,4,6,9,10)
false_1 <- c(8,9,11,12,14,15,16,20,24)
true_2 <- c(10,12,13,18,22,24,28,30)
false_2 <- c(25,29,33,35,40,44,50,53,55,60,61)
true_3 <- c(-2,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,4)
false_3 <- c(1,2,4,5,5,6,6,12)
values <- c(true_1, false_1, true_2, false_2, true_3, false_3)
category <- c(rep("True positives", length(true_1)), rep("False positives", length(false_1)),
              rep("True positives", length(true_2)), rep("False positives", length(false_2)),
              rep("True positives", length(true_3)), rep("False positives", length(false_3)))
method <- c(rep("Method A", length(true_1) + length(false_1)), rep("Method B", length(true_2) + length(false_2)), rep("Method C", length(true_3) + length(false_3)))
my.data.df <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(values, category, method)))
colnames(my.data.df) <- c("Value", "Category", "Method")
write.table(my.data.df, "my_data.txt")
my.data.2.df <- as.data.frame(read.table("my_data.txt"))
give.n <- function(x) {return(c(y=max(x)+(max(x)-min(x))*0.1, label=length(x)))}
ggplot(my.data.2.df, aes(x=factor(Category, levels=c("True positives","False positives")), y=Value)) +
  facet_wrap("Method", scales="free_y") +
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", size=1, color="#808080") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=give.n, geom="text", fun.y=median, size=6, color="#000000") +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#F0F0F0", color="#808080", size=1, outlier.size=5) +
  geom_jitter(colour="#4040FF", position=position_jitter(width=0.3), size=4, alpha=0.4) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12, face="bold"), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(size=12, face="bold"), axis.text.y=element_text(size=12)) +
  ylab("Score")
```

[image: My current plot]

I want to make annotations with results of some calculations on data of each set of true positives (and true positives ONLY):

[image: My desired plot]

So, my question: how can I accomplish this? I know that there are tricks with `stat_summary`, `geom_text`, or `annotate`, with which I can achieve desired result partially, however, I cannot figure out, how to make all the stuff simultaneously:

1) position of annotations - above the maximal value of each box plot

2) specificity to category (I don't want to see any annotations above false positives)

3) calculations of results are made in separate function

**P.S.** In case of 2-dimentional facet grid with applied tip of **lukeA**:

```
true_1 <- c(1,2,3,6,9,10)
true_1_filter <- c(1,2,3,4,6,9,27)
false_1 <- c(8,9,11,12,14,15,16,20,24)
false_1_filter <- c(8,9,11,12,14,15,16,20,24)
true_2 <- c(10,12,13,18,22,24,28,30)
true_2_filter <- c(15,17,19,19,25,30,34,40)
false_2 <- c(25,29,33,35,40,44,50,53,55,60,61)
false_2_filter <- c(30,35,39,42,43,44,60,61)
true_3 <- c(-2,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,4)
true_3_filter <- c(-2,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,4)
false_3 <- c(1,2,4,5,5,6,6,12)
false_3_filter <- c(1,2,4,5,5,6,12)
values <- c(true_1, true_1_filter, false_1, false_1_filter, true_2, true_2_filter, false_2, false_2_filter, true_3, true_3_filter, false_3, false_3_filter)
category <- c(rep("True positives", length(true_1) + length(true_1_filter)), rep("False positives", length(false_1) + length(false_1_filter)),
              rep("True positives", length(true_2) + length(true_2_filter)), rep("False positives", length(false_2) + length(false_2_filter)),
              rep("True positives", length(true_3) + length(true_3_filter)), rep("False positives", length(false_3) + length(false_3_filter)))
method <- c(rep("Method A", length(true_1) + length(true_1_filter) + length(false_1) + length(false_1_filter)),
            rep("Method B", length(true_2) + length(true_2_filter) + length(false_2) + length(false_2_filter)),
            rep("Method C", length(true_3) + length(true_3_filter) + length(false_3) + length(false_3_filter)))
filter <- c(rep("No filter", length(true_1)), rep("Filter", length(true_1_filter)), rep("No filter", length(false_1)), rep("Filter", length(false_1_filter)),
            rep("No filter", length(true_2)), rep("Filter", length(true_2_filter)), rep("No filter", length(false_2)), rep("Filter", length(false_2_filter)),
            rep("No filter", length(true_3)), rep("Filter", length(true_3_filter)), rep("No filter", length(false_3)), rep("Filter", length(false_3_filter)))
my.data.df <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(values, category, method, filter)))
colnames(my.data.df) <- c("Value", "Category", "Method", "Filter")
write.table(my.data.df, "my_data.txt")
my.data.2.df <- as.data.frame(read.table("my_data.txt"))
give.n <- function(x) {return(c(y=max(x)+max((max(x)-min(x))*0.1,1), label=length(x)))}
ggplot(my.data.2.df, aes(x=factor(Category, levels=c("True positives","False positives")), y=Value)) +
  facet_wrap(Filter ~ Method, scales="free_y") +
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", size=1, color="#808080") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=give.n, geom="text", fun.y=median, size=6, color="#000000") +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#F0F0F0", color="#808080", size=1, outlier.size=5) +
  geom_jitter(colour="#4040FF", position=position_jitter(width=0.3), size=4, alpha=0.4) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12, face="bold"), axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(size=12, face="bold"), axis.text.y=element_text(size=12)) +
  ylab("Score") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(Method = levels(my.data.2.df$Method), Filter = levels(my.data.2.df$Filter), Category = "True positives",
                              y = aggregate(Value ~ Method + Filter, data = my.data.2.df[my.data.2.df$Category == "True positives", ], FUN = max)$Value,
                              label = paste0("Result ", LETTERS[1:3], " {}")), 
            aes(y = y, label = label), color = "orange", vjust = -3, fontface = "bold")
```

[image: 2-Dimentional faceted plot after applying the advice]

So, there are still two distinct problems:

1) the order of values in the plot and the new data frame inside `geom_text` does not match

2) some labels go beyond the plot (`vjust` does not work that smoothly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you stored the plot in `p`, you could create another data frame like this:

```
p + geom_text(data = data.frame(Method = levels(my.data.2.df$Method), 
                                Category = "True positives",
                                y = aggregate(Value ~ Method, data = my.data.2.df[my.data.2.df$Category == "True positives", ], FUN = max)$Value,
                                label = paste0("Result ", LETTERS[1:3], " {}")), 
              aes(y = y, 
                  label = label), 
              color = "orange", 
              vjust = -3, 
              fontface = "bold")
```

Result:

[image]

Update:

With regards to the OP's comment, I suggest adjusting the y coordinates of the labels instead of using `vjust`. One way to do so:

```
f <- function(my.data.2.df, yAdj = .2) {
  tmp <- transform(expand.grid(Method = levels(my.data.2.df$Method), 
                        Filter = levels(my.data.2.df$Filter)),
            Category = "True positives",
            y = aggregate(Value ~ Method + Filter, 
                          data = my.data.2.df[my.data.2.df$Category == "True positives", ], 
                          FUN = max)$Value)
  tmp$label <- paste0("Result ", LETTERS[1:nrow(tmp)], " {}")
  y.adjust <- as.vector(diff(t(aggregate(Value ~ Method + Filter, 
                                         data = my.data.2.df, 
                                         FUN = range)$Value))) * yAdj  
  tmp$y <- tmp$y + y.adjust
  return(tmp)
}

p + geom_text(data = f(my.data.2.df), 
            aes(y = y, label = label), color = "orange", fontface = "bold")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But is it still possible to imply this trick to 2-dimentional facet grid (if I have another variable "Type" along with "Method")?

Comment: See P.S. in the question

Comment: For some reason, for me it works with `data.frame()` instead of `transform(expand.grid())`

Comment: And one more thing is missing: how to pass data from selected box plot to an external function? For example, I want instead of {} to display sum of two largest true positive values in each facet?

Comment: @Roman: You could calculate and add the sum of the two largest true positive by using another aggregation `tmp$label <- paste0("Result ", LETTERS[1:nrow(tmp)], ": ", aggregate(Value ~ Method + Filter, data = my.data.2.df[my.data.2.df$Category == "True positives", ], FUN = function(x) sum(tail(sort(x), 2) ))$Value)`. Although there might be room for optimizations...

Comment: Thank you, I got it. One more question: is it possible to apply the same adjustment strategy in the `give.n` function (pass to it the whole range of the facet, not only individual box plot)?